# Using OpenSSL with _huge_ RSA keys

Tags: openssl, rsa

I try to use OpenSSL with huge RSA keys.

Last night, I generated a 65536 bit RSA key (it took me 6 hours).
While OpenSSL seems to be able to generate such keys, it is not able to operate with them:

```
openssl rsautl -inkey 65536.pem -in text.txt -out foo.bar
RSA operation error
139666197399208:error:04067069:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:modulus too large:rsa_eay.c:644:
```

Is it possible to operate with such huge keys?

[here](http://pastebin.com/gPh60GsH)'s the generated key, so you don't need to generate one on your own :)

Comment: Were you able to encrypt and decrypt finally?

Comment: Nope, unfortunatelly not. But perhaps it works with newer versions of OpenSSL.

Answer (score 5):

According to OPENSSL_RSA_MAX_MODULUS_BITS, defined in crypto/rsa/rsa.h, OpenSSL only allows key up to  16384 bits:

```
# define OPENSSL_RSA_MAX_MODULUS_BITS   16384
```

You could try to recompile openssl with a larger value, but I cannot guarantee that it will work.

Comment: Good idea! I tried it out and now it fails with:

RSA operation error
    140580724762280:error:0406706C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len:rsa_eay.c:680: